Improved Formatting of Answer, But Still Downvotes Are There
When I was new to this site, I didn't know much about MathJax formatting. So, in this answer, I used an image instead. Within a few hours, it got downvoted and deleted by some high reputation users. A few days later, I had learnt MathJax formatting, so I decided to undelete and edit my answer, but still the downvotes haven't been removed. Is there still any problem with my answer or have the users who downvoted and voted to delete my answer not checked that it has been improved? Or maybe should I have elaborated more instead of just giving hints on how to proceed?
Any feedback would be highly appreciated and would help me improve my future answers.

There's no point in posting that boilerplate comment under all of your posts here. Users know they can comment, and they do if they feel it is warranted. Moreover, downvotes on meta are not the same as downvotes on main; here, they simply signify disagreement with the views being expressed.

The score on your answer is currently positive.  Your answer seems fine.
Unfortunately, it is rare that people return after an edit to remove the downvote they cast on the original version.  This is not a good thing, but it is the way things often are.  The best you can do is improve your answer as much as possible, hope that others upvote it (counteracting the downvotes), and take it as a lesson for the future about how to write answers that will be better-received from the start in the future.

The one addition that I would make is to try to time your update.  If you update your answer in the middle of the night, when there are fewer reviewers, then once the morning rolls around, your update may be off the front page because of the overnight posted questions.  I suggest making your update around 7am pacific standard time.
